# SQL Server returns wrong UTC time for the function GETUTCDATE

Tags: sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012, timezone

Our server is in CST timezone in the USA and CST timezone is 6 hours behind UTC timezone. Since it is daylight saving time, now the difference is 5 hours.

`GETDATE` function returns the correct local time, but `GETUTCDATE` returns a wrong UTC time. `GETUTCDATE` returns the time that is 7 hours (UTC+2:00) ahead of CST.

Checked the server's timezone and it is set to CST time zone (UTC - 6:00) and the option "Set timezone automatically" was off.

I am not sure what else to check for.

Answer (score 0):

"Set time zone automatically" is a convenience added in Windows 10 / Server 2016. It uses available location information to set the time zone.  It isn't necessary, and really shouldn't matter on a server.  In fact, a best practice is to deliberately set servers to the UTC time zone, so that local time difference don't interfere.  You may wish to consider that option.

However, there are a few things to check:

1. Is your server's clock synchronized to a reliable time source?

   - If your server is in a domain, then are the domain controller's clocks synchronized to an Internet-based time source or some other reliable time source?
   - If not in a domain, do you have "Set time automatically" or "Internet Time" turned on? Or some other mechanism for setting the clock correctly?
   - If not sure where the clock is synchronized, try `w32tm /query /source` from an elevated command prompt.
   - If you just want to check the raw UTC time, try `[DateTime]::UtcNow` from Powershell.  (None of the time zone or DST settings will affect the result.)
2. If the system is configured for a local time zone, is "Adjust for daylight saving time automatically" (or "Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time" in the older control-panel setting) turned on?  This setting should really never be disabled. It is there for legacy purposes only.

   - If not sure, try `tzutil /g` on a comand prompt.  If the result has `_dstoff` in the name, then you should go turn it back on.